# Following symlink to run from current directory

Tags: linux, hyperlink, sh

I have a script `run.sh` located somewhere on read only directory `/install/app/release_1.0.0/` and a symbolic link to that script in the fully accessed directory `/packages/app/`. This script operates with files using relative paths. When I'm running this script using symbolic link it's not able to locate files because it's looking in the current directory of symbolic link. How can I force it to look into the current directory of link's target? Changing the script is not prefered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use a symlink, use a wrapper instead.  Remove `/packages/app/run.sh` and create a new file at that location, with these contents:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /install/app/release_1.0.0/
./run.sh
```

Mark it executable (`chmod +x run.sh`) and that should do it.

Comment: Good point, thanks. Actually links mastering performed by another script during installation process. I'd like to keep it as straightforward as possible but in this case a have to rewrite it instead changing link target.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately there's no way (at least not that I know of) to do this using just a symlink.

Comment: Thanks, let me wait a bit for other presumable way and than accept this.

Comment: Could you advise the best way to pass arguments through the wrapper to target script?

Comment: Yes, change `./run.sh` to `./run.sh "$@"`.